# deploying heroku using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

have followed all of the Heroku / Rails 4.2 information for deploying . For some reason my heroku app keeps crashing on deployment and I don't know  what going over here.my logs are below

2016-05-30T03:01:57.978367+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2016-05-30T03:01:58.856349+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-30T03:01:58.859528+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978357+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in`start'
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978358+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978360+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in`tap'
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978362+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978363+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978365+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2016-05-30T03:01:58.856349+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978357+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in`start'
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978363+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978367+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in`'
2016-05-30T03:01:58.859528+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978357+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978360+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in`block in server'
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978365+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978367+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in`'
2016-05-30T03:01:58.859528+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978357+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978358+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in`start'
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978362+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978363+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
2016-05-30T03:01:57.978365+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2016-05-30T03:01:58.859528+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

Comment: Does it work fine on your local machine?

Comment: i get an application error message

Comment: How would you expect to work on heroku if you get an application error message on local machine?

Comment: Yeah the heroku build will fail if you have errors, fix any errors you have locally first before you try deploying to heroku.